# Blazor Server app with cookie authentication - Roles not working

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, cookie-authentication

I have a Blazor server app, I implemented cookie auth as shown in: https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/asp.net-core-identity-setup-in-blazor-application/

I can succesfully protect my page with `<AuthorizeView>` and `@attribute [Authorize]`.
But I cant get my roles to work, when I use for example: `@attribute [Authorize (Roles = "Installer"]` it keeps telling me "Not authorized".

The user and the roles are present in the database (it works with my Blazor WASM project with individual user auth) so I think that cant be the problem.

Did anyone encoutered this problem before??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have something similar to this in your Startup class:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => 
     options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: That was the trick, I first looked in my startup.cs but I use cookie auth so I had to put the .Addroles in my IdentityHostingStartup class.